# Why did I receive an electric shock from my microwave?

Tags: electrical

I was doing the washing up and the microwave is next to the place where I put the dishes and I went to put it down and my hand touched the side of the microwave and I got an electric shock for a bout 2-3 seconds (felt like vibrating in my hand). I checked the plug socket when I was feeling better and the switch was not on. how could this happen?

It was a double socket in the wall the microwave one was switched off and the other one was on.

Answer (score 6):

This is why GFCI sockets are used in kitchens.

It sounds like you have a bad ground circuit or possibly switched hot and neutral wires on the sockets.

Time to call in an electrician before someone dies.

My congratulations on your survival, we once lived in a house that developed some sort of issue that caused the cold water tap outside the front door to be hot. I found out about the **bite** and dangers of electricity when I was 5 years old.

Comment: I second the notice to call in the electrician. Do it as soon as possible. You will never forgive yourself if a family member gets electrocuted trying to use the microwave when at the same time you knew there was a shock hazard present. If your kitchen does not have GFI outlets get them installed when the electrician comes out.